# jQuery .hide() doesn't hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

When finished parsing the json into the specified span tags I wanted to automatically hide the imperial tags currentimperial and forecastimperial but when I try to do this use

```
$('#currentimperial').hide();

$('#forecastimperial').hide();
```

and view the result in chrome and look in the console I see that instead of

```
style="display: none; "
```

they actually have

```
style="display: inline; "
```

Here is my whole javascript and html on jsBin http://jsbin.com/efaguv/edit#javascript,html

Thanks for any help I recieve.

Comment: Can you show the relevant JS and html in your question? Your jsbin link seems to just have the default jsbin "hello world" html rather than your html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you haven't allowed for the fact that your ajax call is asynchronous.

A much simplified example of what's happening:

```
1 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
2   $('#warning').remove('#warning');   
3   $.ajax({
4        url: 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/APIKEYREMOVED/geolookup/conditions/forecast/q/51.773079,-1.591353.json',
5        dataType: "jsonp",
6        success: function(parsed_json) {
7           $('#currentimperial').fadeIn(1000).append(+temp_f+ '&#8457; ');
8        }
9    });
10 
11   $('#celcius').hide();
12   $('#currentimperial').hide();
13   $('#forecastimperial').hide();
14 });
```

- line 2 executes
- line 3 executes to make the ajax request (response will be received at some point in the future)
- lines 11-13 execute to hide the items
- line 14: your document ready function completes
- (eventually) ajax response is received and success handler is called so line 7 executes.

Because (in your full code) the ajax success callback makes the elements visible (using `.fadeIn()`) the end result is that they are visible.

Can you instead hide the elements within that ajax success callback?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the .fadeIn() was causing them to become visible again, I changed the .fadeIn() to .hide() for the imperial spans and it works as I wanted now, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$('#currentimperial').slideUp();
```

or

```
document.getElementById('currentimperial').style.display="none";
```

Comment: I think it's `.slideUp()`, not `.slideUP`. And with Javascript, `.getElementById()` takes just the `id`, not `#id`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue where hide was not hiding. I am using angular and found that a directive was using the `!important` css feature on the `display` style attribute forcing it to remain a block and preventing hide from changing the display to none.

`elem.attr('style', 'display: none !important;');`